# OpenCV CvBoost get Probability/Reliability like in CvRTrees::predict_prob

Tags: c++, opencv

Does anyone of you know who I can get the probability of the classification when using the CvBoost (CvBoost::REAL) Classification? I have it working using RandomTrees (CvRTrees::predict_prob) but the CvBoost function does not offer a similiar function.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/boosting.html#cvboost

Many thanks in advance for your support!